# Regular expression for strings not containing brackets

Tags: regex, procmail

I am trying to edit my .procmailrc file to get rid of junk.

The account is from the CS departments at my school, all the emails within the department have subjects with brackets in them for instance:

> [Majors] Some Subject

or:

> [Undergrads] Another Subject

I get a LOT of spam not caught by the filters but almost all of them don't include brackets. I want to move these emails into a folder for spam but can't figure out the REGEX. Any regex masters out there that can help?

Comment: You can match an open bracket with `[[]` or match all characters except an open bracket with `[^[]`. The full list of `regex` supported by `procmail` is in `man 5 procmailrc`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple Procmail recipe for `Subject:` headers which do not contain an opening square bracket is simply

```
:0   # Add a second colon if the spam box is an mbox folder
* ^Subject:[^[]*$
spam
```

This simply checks for an opening square bracket and ignores the possibility that you could receive legitimate mail which only contains a closing square bracket (I think it's spammy by itself anyway).

... But for completeness, I'll mention that if you want a closing square bracket in there, that's a special case which requires a particular ordering in the character class (just like a dash needs to go first or last to disambiguate it from a character range).  A commonly seen character class of this type is `[^][]` which is a negated character class containing closing square bracket and an opening square bracket. They need to be precisely in this order for it to work; in any other position, the closing square bracket would close the character class. (You can't backslash-escape it in there either; backslashes in character classes are literal.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I think that the close bracket issue you explained is the exact problem I was running into. This works great and does actually work with procmail.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup your `.procmailrc` in a specific order to help accomplish what you desire. `procmail` reads `procmailrc` and stops with the first recipe that matches. Therefore, you can do all of your regular processing at the beginning of the file, and at the end add something similar to the following at the end.

This example tests the subject for the presence of `[` and keeps those messages. Any messages that do not match any other recipes and don't contain a `[` in the subject are moved to `spam-probably` (the example uses a `good` folder for keeping mail, and a `spam-probably` folder to move unmatched messages to -- adjust the names to fit your setup)

```
:0:                        # keep mail with [ in 'good' folder
* ^Subject:.*\[
good

:0:                        # move unmatched to 'spam-probably' folder
spam-probably
```

**Note:** by not having a condition line in the `spam-probably` recipe, procmail will move all messages that have not previously matched a recipe to the `spam-probably` folder. There are literally dozens of `regexs` you can choose from to accomplish your subject match on `[` depending on how tight or loose you want to match. Look at the regexes that will accomplish what you need and substitute as needed.